# ComboBox not losing focus

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, combobox

I've been having problems with the ComboBox control. I'm no expert in GUI, but I know this problem is related to the control's focus.

For some reason, the ComboBox does not lose its focus when I click outside of it. Say for example:

1. I click on the ComboBox to list its items.
2. I select one item. This closes the ComboBox.
3. I click on the second ComboBox, the first one stays focused.

OR

1. Click on a ComboBox (contains Point, Solid and Wireframe).
2. Click on the form. Press either P, S or W. See the selection get changed.

Note that the ComboBox only has the *DropDownStyle* set to *ComboBoxStyle.DropDownList*. This means that it's the default ComboBox behavior. I thought that the default behavior was that the ComboBox would lose its focus when you clicked out of it, or on another control (button or ComboBox). It is not the case here, why?

**UPDATE:** 
What I need is some sort of ActiveComponent = null. The behavior should be similar to the one of Visual Studio were you select Debug or Release (ComboBox) in the standard toolbar. Currently, if I click outside of the ComboBox, it is still focused.

Comment: I've tried it and I see no trace of this behaviour. What version of the framework are you using?

Comment: Have you set any property which disallows it from showing it as focused? AllowSelection?

Comment: I suggest you create another form from scratch and see if the behavior differs. Then do a diff between current form and the new form to see - what is the reason?

Answer (score 19):

You may want to take a look at [This topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/290629).  Try setting CausesValidation to false on the combo box, see if you can leave it.  If an exception is thrown in the OnValidating event handler, it won't deselect the box.

Answer (score 3):

Are you sure the problem isn't because neither your frame or your other combobox have a way to gain focus?

Answer (score 3):

All you have to do is:

1. go to property window of Combobox
2. and set **Allow Drop="true"**

The property is intended for some other purpose but it works for this scenario too.

Comment: I had the same problem with a TextBox being the only focusable control on a UserControl. Setting `AllowDrop=true` magically solved the problem.

Answer (score 2):

So what exactly are you saying?  Are you saying that your _LostFocus() event handler is not being called?  If so, the first place I would look is in your designer-generated event handler mapping code.  Sometimes that has a way of being disassociated by doing certain things in the designer (it's rare these days, though...)

Comment: I do not have defined any custom Leave event for the ComboBox, but if I do and set breakpoints, I can see it's clearly not called.

Answer (score 2):

I experienced a similar problem, but the control was recursively losing and regaining focus; the `LostFocus` event handler was being called, but the control immediately regained focus. Setting the `CausesValidation` property to `false` had no effect.

In my case, I had bound to the `SelectedValue` property instead of the `Text` property when binding to a custom object. Because I manually specified the ComboBox item collection and did not provide a data source, the `ValueMember` property was missing or invalid (so of course the `SelectedValue` property was no use.)

Changing my binding to use the `Text` property solved the issue.

Comment: For my purposes I ended up choosing SelectedItem over Text, because apparently the TextChanged event only fires when the collection item is selected by the mouse, and not the keyboard. SelectedIndexChanged seems to fire regardless of input device.

Answer (score 1):

I had the similar problem and tried all the method you guys suggested. Unfortunately, none of them works. Here is my "simple" solution: send a "ESC" key stoke after you change the SelectedIndex.

```
ComboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
# do whatever you were doing
...
...
  SendKeys.Send("{ESC}");
}
```

It worked for me.

Comment: My solution is to set ActiveControl = null; instead of using SendKeys.Send("{ESC}");. It does the job and it's cleaner in term of code, but coding this behavior is not what I would expect.

Answer (score 1):

Try Leave event instead of LostFocus.
Try Enter event instead of GotFocus.

Answer (score 1):

1. After `SendKeys.Send("{ESC}")`; `ComboBox` still regains focus;
2. Setting `CausesValidation` to false on the combo box didn't help me as well.

Here is how I resolved this problem:

Suppose you have another control, for example `System.Windows.Forms.PictureBox pbxChart`, and user wants to move focus right there, after changing values in `combobox (selecting by Left Click or MouseWheel)`.
So I added :

```
    private void pbxChart_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        pbxChart.Focus();
    }
```

in `MouseClick EventHandler`, which resolved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

In `***form.Designer.vb` you have some code for each combobox like:

```
'OrgDetailsIDComboBox
'
Me.OrgDetailsIDComboBox.DataBindings.Add(New System.Windows.Forms.Binding("Text", Me.MedicoLegalBindingSource, "OrgDetailsID", True))
Me.OrgDetailsIDComboBox.DataBindings.Add(New System.Windows.Forms.Binding("SelectedValue", Me.MedicoLegalBindingSource, "OrgDetailsID", True))
Me.OrgDetailsIDComboBox.DataSource = Me.OrgBindingSource
Me.OrgDetailsIDComboBox.DisplayMember = "Place"
```

I fixed the problem by commenting out the first line of code (includes string `Forms.Binding("Text", )`. So it seems only the statement for `SelectedValue` is required.

Answer (score 0):

The dictionary that combobox take the values has, type index, type value, the type index have to be the same type in your class properity bindingded on combobox. If the types was diferent the combobox never will lose focus.

Answer (score 0):

I know this has been a while for this post, but maybe it would help someone in the future who comes across the same problem. I struggled for few days with this, but finally figures it out.

if you set CauseViolation to false, then you are not solving the problem and databinding stops working.

When you mind SelectedItem to the property like so

```
combobox.DataBindings.Add("SelectedItem", someObject, "MySelectedItemProperty", false, DataSourceUpdateMode.OnPropertyChanged)
```

combobox calls the Equals method of the object that you use in the list which assigned to your DataSource.  In my case, I needed to overwrite Equals method in this object.  For whatever stupid reason, combobox calls this method and passes System.DBNull before actually passing the right object type for comparison.  This is where violation occurred in my case and causing violation to fail, hence not releasing the cursor from the combobox.   Also the weird part was that the program did not stop when Exception was caused in my Equals method.

Once I added this code

```
 if (obj.GetType() != this.GetType())
       return false;
```

to my Equals method, everything worked fine.  Hope it helps someone.

Answer (score 0):

```
 private void drp_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.KeyChar == 13)
            {
                SendKeys.Send("{TAB}");
            }
        }
```

or use

this code on control leave function :

```
 private void drp_Leave(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
            {

                    SendKeys.Send("{TAB}");

            }
```

Comment: Please elaborate on how this code answers the question.

Comment: if we have two controls eg combobox and another grid...mark the tabindex 1 for combobox and 2 for grid....then after selecting value from combobox and press enter ...then the tab key used to function in the case of combobox so the combobox  lose the focus and grid on focus.

Answer (score 0):

The way I did it as follow.

**Step 1 - Create a method that returns all given controls on the form**

```
    public IEnumerable<Control> GetAllControls(Control control, Type type)
    {
        var controls = control.Controls.Cast<Control>();
        return controls.SelectMany(ctrl => GetAllControls(ctrl, type))
                                  .Concat(controls)
                                  .Where(c => c.GetType() == type);
    }
```

**Step 2 - Create a custom event**

```
    private void ChangeComboFocus(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        SendKeys.Send("{TAB}");
    }
```

**Step 3 - Bind the event finally on form load**

```
    private void ClientRegistrationForm_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var comboxes=_Helper.GetAllControls(this, typeof(ComboBox)).ToList();
        if (comboxes != null)
        {
            foreach (ComboBox item in comboxes)
            {
                item.SelectedIndexChanged +=new EventHandler(this.ChangeComboFocus) ;
            }
        }
    }
```