# Windows Forms ComboBox Steals Focus Until an Item is Selected

Tags: c#, winforms, combobox, focus, user-experience

I've run into a peculiar issue while using the standard Windows Forms `ComboBox`.
Essentially, if I click the `ComboBox`, then click it a second time or hit escape to exit the drop-down, focus is stolen. The animation below shows how this is done:

[image: ComboBox Stealing Focus]

When the focus is stolen, `WM_SETFOCUS` messages are not received, and this has some interesting consequences:

- <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>F4</kbd> command does not close the activated window.
- Clicking tabs on a `TabControl` does not switch pages.
- The focused control cannot be switched using <kbd>Tab</kbd> or <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Tab</kbd>.

As one can imagine, this leaves the application in an unacceptable state because users may not know why, or more importantly, how to resolve this focusing issue and are left thinking there is a bug because of the unresponsiveness.

After some testing, I found that focus can be restored by selecting an item from the offending `ComboBox`.

#### What can be done to prevent the combo-box from stealing the focus when the drop-down list is exited without selecting an item?

---

I've gathered some logs from Spy++ that demonstrate the third bullet (switching focus).
As can be seen, the tab key is pressed but `WM_SETFOCUS` is not monitored by Spy++.

```
<000434> 0025574E R WM_NCCALCSIZE fuValidRect:0000 lpncsp:007CE9CC
<000435> 0025574E S WM_NCCALCSIZE fCalcValidRects:True lpncsp:007CE9CC
<000436> 0025574E R WM_NCCALCSIZE fuValidRect:0000 lpncsp:007CE9CC
<000437> 0025574A P WM_LBUTTONUP fwKeys:0000 xPos:237 yPos:26
<000438> 0025574E P WM_LBUTTONDOWN fwKeys:MK_LBUTTON xPos:236 yPos:-7
<000439> 0025574A P WM_LBUTTONUP fwKeys:0000 xPos:237 yPos:26
<000440> 0025574A P WM_KEYDOWN nVirtKey:VK_TAB cRepeat:1 ScanCode:0F fExtended:0 fAltDown:0 fRepeat:0 fUp:0
<000441> 0025574A P WM_KEYUP nVirtKey:VK_TAB cRepeat:1 ScanCode:0F fExtended:0 fAltDown:0 fRepeat:1 fUp:1
<000442> 0025574A P WM_KEYDOWN nVirtKey:VK_TAB cRepeat:1 ScanCode:0F fExtended:0 fAltDown:0 fRepeat:0 fUp:0
<000443> 0025574A P WM_KEYUP nVirtKey:VK_TAB cRepeat:1 ScanCode:0F fExtended:0 fAltDown:0 fRepeat:1 fUp:1
<000444> 0025574A P WM_KEYDOWN nVirtKey:VK_TAB cRepeat:1 ScanCode:0F fExtended:0 fAltDown:0 fRepeat:0 fUp:0
<000445> 0025574A P WM_KEYUP nVirtKey:VK_TAB cRepeat:1 ScanCode:0F fExtended:0 fAltDown:0 fRepeat:1 fUp:1
<000446> 0025574A P WM_KEYDOWN nVirtKey:VK_TAB cRepeat:1 ScanCode:0F fExtended:0 fAltDown:0 fRepeat:0 fUp:0
```

However, after we select and item in the drop-down list, focus is able to change and Spy++ captures `WM_SETFOCUS` messages.

```
<000742> 002555E0 S WM_NCCALCSIZE fCalcValidRects:True lpncsp:007CCFA4
<000743> 002555E0 R WM_NCCALCSIZE fuValidRect:0000 lpncsp:007CCFA4
<000744> 002555E0 S WM_NCCALCSIZE fCalcValidRects:True lpncsp:007CCC94
<000745> 002555E0 R WM_NCCALCSIZE fuValidRect:0000 lpncsp:007CCC94
<000746> 0025574E R WM_KEYDOWN
<000747> 0025574A P WM_KEYUP nVirtKey:VK_DOWN cRepeat:1 ScanCode:50 fExtended:1 fAltDown:0 fRepeat:1 fUp:1
<000748> 0025574A P WM_KEYDOWN nVirtKey:VK_TAB cRepeat:1 ScanCode:0F fExtended:0 fAltDown:0 fRepeat:0 fUp:0
<000749> 0025574A S WM_KILLFOCUS hwndGetFocus:00265748
<000750> 0025574A R WM_KILLFOCUS
<000751> 00265748 S WM_SETFOCUS hwndLoseFocus:0025574A
<000752> 00265748 R WM_SETFOCUS
<000753> 00265748 P WM_KEYUP nVirtKey:VK_TAB cRepeat:1 ScanCode:0F fExtended:0 fAltDown:0 fRepeat:1 fUp:1
<000754> 00265748 P WM_KEYDOWN nVirtKey:VK_TAB cRepeat:1 ScanCode:0F fExtended:0 fAltDown:0 fRepeat:0 fUp:0
<000755> 00265748 S WM_KILLFOCUS hwndGetFocus:00255770
<000756> 00265748 R WM_KILLFOCUS
```

I had initially thought that act of stealing focus was a side-effect of the `ComboBox` creating a new window for the drop-down display without properly re-activating the parent window. But clicking the application icon in the task bar will cause the `WM_ACTIVATE` message to appear in Spy++ without retrieving focus again.

Comment: why not as soon as the drop down menu closes,you focus on the form ?

Comment: This seemed like a great idea, but calling `this.Focus()` on the `DropDownClosed` event will not prevent the `ComboBox` from interfering with the focus. Spy++ still shows that `WM_SETFOCUS` is not sent as tab/shift+tab are pressed.

Comment: are u sure my idea won't work ? why nt create a txtbox,hide it and set focus to it on drop down close ? i know its not the best practice but worth a shot right ?

Comment: For kicks, I even wrapped that in a timer to trigger 1 second after closing the drop-down to ensure that it wasn't being overridden. Still no luck, but as  OP indicates, selecting an item still fixes the focus-lock ;)

Comment: @zackraiyan As described, I was not able to produce an MVCE...will update OP as more information is found.

Comment: Sigh, if only I could copy/paste code instead of having my eyes assaulted by an animated gif.  My crystal ball says that you need to pay  attention to WM_ACTIVATE, it is a known problem with ToolStrip.

Comment: Why do you say that focus is stolen? It took me quite a while to understand this. Nothing is stolen, you are in the dropdown so the focus stays there. Collapsing it won't make the dropdown lose the focus. That wouldn't be the standard behavior of any application. Are you saying the the control you set focus to after collapsing it is not actually in focus?

Comment: It's perhaps the best I way I understand how to describe this behavior. Truly, the issue is that upon exiting the dropdown, it is not possible to set the focus to any other control. At least not until the item is selected. I recognize this is not the standard behavior of the combo-box, so there is likely some side-effect that causes the combo-box to exhibit this behavior.

Comment: Not sure what you are talking about here. I tried creating a sample app and when I close the combobox without selecting an item, I still can close the form with Alt F4, tab to other controls etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want to check out this topic here:

[Cannot tab out of databound Winforms dropdown list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/290629/cannot-tab-out-of-databound-winforms-dropdown-list)

The databinding might be throwing an exception in the data validation behind the scenes.

Comment: Perfect! This was it!